# Catching and printing the Warning message on Python > Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to catch a warning message, print the warning message, and then exit out of a test case with a passing state.  Within the test case, I have the following code:

testcase.py:

```
try:
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    activeConfig(driver, url, None, None, True).confirmConfigSet()
except Warning as e:
    print e.message
    return
```

As I'm able to catch the warning without any issues, I'll only display the warning that's actually caught:

```
code-where-warning-is-caught.py:
    .
    .
    .
    except (Exception, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        global_vars.attemptedToEnableDatabase = True
        warnings.warn("\nWARNING : DATABASE PACKAGES HAVE NOT BEEN INSTALLED SO THE DATABASE CANNOT BE ENABLED.", UserWarning)
        return
```

I can catch the warning just fine, but I keep getting the following error:

```
E           DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of
Python 2.6
```

If I remove the 'e' parts of the test case code to look like...

```
try:
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    activeConfig(driver, url, None, None, True).confirmConfigSet()
except Warning:
    return
```

...the test case runs EXACTLY the way I want it to, except it doesn't print the warning message.  How do I catch the exception, print the warning message, and exit out of the test case with a passing state?  I'm also open to any improvement ideas a more experienced coder may have.

Comment: Did you try out sys.exc_info() ? It returns a triple of three items , the first and second elements maybe what you want .

Comment: Thanks @Anand S Kumar.  I played with this a bit & was able to get the message I wanted using 'sys.exc_info()[1]'.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a read here. They have everything explained, you can experiment with them a bit.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

In my recent project, I managed to write critical only messages to a text file by doing this,

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL,
                    format = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', 
                    datefmt = '%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename = self.testResultRecord,
                    filemode = 'w')
```

lines below are my personal formatting configurations, which have nothing to do with logging level.

```
format = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', 
datefmt = '%m-%d %H:%M',
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Yu Zhang.  It looks like this traceback probably would work, but I never could figured out how to limit the information to just the warning message.

Comment: @rwbyrd, ha, that is not a problem. Check this out, https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels. Basically, you can configure which level of message you want to see. I edited my original answer so you can have read.

Comment: @rwbyrd, get back to me if you are still unsure of anything. :-)